# Xamarin - Android Scroll All content on Keyboard Pop up

Tags: android, layout, xamarin.android

I am using simple Scroll View along with a nested table view of a fragment. While the scroll view works OK along with the android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" attributes, I would ideally like the user be able to scroll the entire view till the end above the keyboard. The screen shows the editText above the keyboard but hides the save button after it. The user has to close the keyboard to see the save button.

---

Its very natural for people to scroll up to click the "Save" button instead of closing the keyboard and then clicking "Save" at the end of the form.

---

I tried adding padding etc to the last control to artificially increase the height of the view but does not work as expected and it might change based on screen size, and orientation. The simple requirement is to allow the user to scroll the view above the keyboard to get the last item (i.e. Save Button) visible.

How do I do this to make sure it works across devices and orientations?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"         
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:padding="16dp">

  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"    
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="false">

  <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"    
        android:stretchColumns="1"
      >


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cmbSaleType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:entries="@array/sale_type_choices"
        android:hint="Sale Type"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/txtLayoutClient"
      >

      <EditText 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Customer"
            android:text="Client"
            android:id="@+id/txtclient"
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:inputType="date"
                  android:hint="Date"
                  android:text=""
                  android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Job Type"
            android:text="HairCut"
            android:id="@+id/txtjob"
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="Amount"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/txtAmount"
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="KM"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/txtKM"
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"        
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
      />

  </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: So, you want the the content scroll by KeyBoard's height?

Comment: I have test you layout, but I don't understand your mean. If you just want to show the button after input `txtKM`, you can scroll the `ScrollView` by a height of your button. Is that you want? Because you didn't provide your c# code, so I just seen the keyboard popup when open the page and maybe the `JobType` get focus firstly which I think is wrong. So I hope you can perfect your question and give me a question clearly.

Comment: Was able to solve it by removing some of the layout attributes. The requirement was to make sure the text field remains visible when a pop up keyboard comes up. The text field would go behind the keyboard, and in one case while things worked for text field, it hid away a drop down below it, to which I have not found a solution as yet. I simply moved the dropdown at the top of the screen, but I know  that is not a solution.